# column name not displayed in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

The following code is now showing the column names in data table when "columns" filed of datatables is set to "colArray", but it shows when it is set to "colname1". Can somebody help what I am missing here?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var dataSet = [
        ["Tiger", "10", "20", "51", "3", "2", "1"],
        ["Hyena","10","20","51","3","2 ","1 "]];


       var  colname1= [
                { title: "Column0 " },
                { title: "column1 " },
                { title: "column2 " },
                { title: "column3 " },
                { title: "column4 "}];

        colArray = new Array();
        colArray.push({Values : " Name "});
        $.each(colname1, function(index, value){
            colArray.push({Values : colname1[index].Values});
        });
        colArray.push({Values : "lastcol"});

       $(document).ready(function() {

            var t = $('#example').DataTable({
                data: dataSet,
                columns:colArray
              //columns: colname1
            });


      });
  </script>

  <div>
    <table width="300" class="display" id="example"></table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `columns` should be this way:

```
columns: [
    { title: "Name" },
    { title: "Position" },
    { title: "Office" },
    { title: "Extn." },
    { title: "Start date" },
    { title: "Salary" }
]
```

But you have given `Values`. See this snippet:

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Tiger", "10", "20", "51", "3", "2", "1"],
  ["Hyena", "10", "20", "51", "3", "2 ", "1 "]
];
var colname1 = [{
  title: "Column0"
}, {
  title: "column1"
}, {
  title: "column2"
}, {
  title: "column3"
}, {
  title: "column4"
}];

colArray = [];
colArray.push({
  title: "Name"
});
$.each(colname1, function(index, value) {
  colArray.push({
    title: value.title
  });
});
colArray.push({
  title: "lastcol"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: colArray
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table width="300" class="display" id="example">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks it works. So, does this means datables will pick up the "title" and not "Values" when looking for column names in array?